# Enabling warning of undefined variable in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm version 2019.2. Previously, whenever I used an undefined variable in my code, PyCharm would underline this variable and give me a warning, before I even ran the code. However, something has recently changed, and now I do not see this warning.

For example, if I have a blank script with the only line being `x = y`, previously the `y` would be underlined, and there would be a warning saying something like `undefined variable`.

How can I get these warning messages back?

---

Update:

I have found a minimal example that shows the problem. If I have a script with just this:

```
while True:
    x = y
```

Then there is a warning message under `y`.

But if my script is:

```
while True:
    x = y
    if 0:
        pass
```

Then there is no warning message under `y`.

If I remove the outer `while` loop, or change `if 0:` to `if 1:`, then the warning message appears again.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: This works in 2019.3 but not for all open files (e.g. they may need to be part of your project's SourcesRoot).